# "keep-alive" header in customer HttpHandler

Tags: c#, .net, httphandler, keep-alive

.Net IIS7 :

I Implemented a customer IHttpHandle interface . It responds each request with "Connection:Close".

So I added following code to append keep-alive header manually

```
Context.Response.AppendHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
```

But It doesn't work .

Anyone ?

Comment: It doesn't work because the header is just not appended or you are getting an exception? What's the .NET version in your application pool? Are you using Integrated or Classic mode?

Comment: There are not any exception was thrown . I use vs2010 , .NET 4.0 . I think just Classic mode in ASP.NET Web Development Server. But after I publish to IIS by using Integrated mode , I got the same result.